# How to use C# code to create an Excel sheet that contains a pivot table which has direct connection to my database using a query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ms-office, vba

I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** dll, and I want to create an excel sheet which gets data from database using a query, either in the form of pivot tables or in the form of Data Table.
**I don't want to get data using my C# code and then insert into Excel Sheet. I want my Excel sheet that has been generated to have a connection directly to database using that query. Is it possible and how to do it?** 
Please help.

Comment: You could use Query Tables or create a PivotTable, and when creating the querytable or pivotCache to the PivotTable, you must specify some Refresh/Connection properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, how about this?

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connection = @"OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=MYDATASOURCE;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2017";
            var command = "SELECT * FROM [Sales].[vSalesPersonSalesByFiscalYears]";
            var xl = new Application
            {
                Visible = true
            };
            xl.Workbooks.Add();
            var pivotCache = xl.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, null);
            pivotCache.Connection = connection;
            pivotCache.MaintainConnection = true;
            pivotCache.CommandText = command;
            pivotCache.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdSql;
            var sheet = (Worksheet)xl.ActiveSheet;
            var pivotTables = (PivotTables)sheet.PivotTables();
            var pivotTable = pivotTables.Add(pivotCache, xl.ActiveCell, "PivotTable1");
            pivotTable.SmallGrid = false;
            pivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = true;
            pivotTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight1";
            PivotField pageField = (PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("SalesTerritory");
            pageField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
            PivotField rowField = (PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("FullName");
            rowField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotTable.PivotFields("2004"), "Sum of 2004", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
        }
    }
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I used a console app, but adapt it to fit whatever way you're working with the code.

I don't pretend to have originated all this code, I adapted it from:

[Creating a PivotTable programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/07/25/creating-a-pivottable-programmatically/)

updating it for AdventureWorks2017 and Excel Interop.

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: This code produces an exception in the last line. Still, I got what I needed to know. Will fix the exception.

Comment: Ok. It worked on my setup when I ran it, so I'll be interested to know what the exception was and how you fixed it. Cheers!